# how to input a string of charater(100,101,102.....)(number of character is unlimited) and store numbers in array in C

Tags: c++

i'm new member. And now, i'm having a exercise: "input a string of character(100,101,102...)(number of character is unlimited) and store numbers in array". My teacher provide us a function. It is ReadWord to read a number in the string. But i still have 2 issues. 1st, in the "for" loop, when i put the "puts" command to print the array's elements, i can't print the last element. And if i put the "puts" command outside of "for" loop, i can't print any element. Please tell me why and how to fixed it. Thanks you very much!

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include<conio.h>
const int MAX_NUM_LEN = 7; 
const int MAX_LINE_LEN = 50; 

int IsComma(int ch) { 
return (ch == ','); 
}
int ReadWord(char *num) {  
int ch, pos = 0; 
ch = getchar(); 
while (IsComma(ch)) 
   ch = getchar(); 
while (!IsComma(ch) && (ch != EOF)) {  
  if (pos < MAX_NUM_LEN) {  
     num[pos] = (char)ch;  
     pos++;  
 }  
  ch = getchar();  
 }  
num[pos] = '\0';  
return pos;  
}  

int main()
{
int i,j;
int count;
char **ds;
ds=new char *[50];
for (i=0;i<50;i++) ds[i]=new char [3];
char  num[MAX_NUM_LEN + 1]; 
int numLen;  
    char line[MAX_LINE_LEN + 1]; 
    int lineLen = 0;  
    i=0;count=0; 
    for (;;) { 
       numLen = ReadWord(num); 
       if (numLen == 0) break; 
       strcpy(ds[i],num);
   puts(ds[i]);
       i++;
} 
    j=i;
    printf("\n %d",j);
    for(i=0;i<j;i++) printf("%s ",ds[i]);
    for(i=0;i<j;i++) delete ds[i];
    delete []ds;
    getch();    
}
```

Comment: C? Really? `ds = new char *[50];`? Also, you better pipe your code through `indent` in order me not to vomit.

Comment: Retagged as C++. It is not a C syntax

Comment: Please say what you input, and what you see as output. 'Can't print the last element' is not very helpful. You have a few errors, but the obvious one is that `new char [3]` is not big enough.

Comment: are you terminating your last input with a comma?

Comment: more specifically, haw are you terminating your last number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your code and confirmed that the readword function is not recognizing EOF as a method of terminating. I changed it to 10 (LF) and it now recognizes the enter key and prints out all numbers. The problem is that getchar does not handle EOF the way one would expect. There are plenty of examples here on SO that talk about that.

Also, john is right, you have a few other bugs floating around that will cause you grief.

Comment: Thanks hvanbrug, after i changed "EOF" into "10", i've solved my problem. Thank you so much!!

Comment: My pleasure. :) Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if you are satisfied with it.